# Maintaining uptime while rotating secrets in AWS

Tags: aws-secrets-manager

I don't understand the mechanics of AWS Secrets Manager *alternating users password* rotation strategy.

Here's what I **understand**:

- One password is configured in the secret. Applications will use the
  password to connect to the db/service etc.
- On the 1st rotation, a
  second user with a new password (cloned from the original) is created
  under the secret.
- On further rotations, the user who's password is changed is
  alternated

Here's what I **don't** understand:

- How does this help with uptime?
- Should the application be configured
  to use the "cloned" user for n number of connections so that only 50%
  of your users experience the blip in connectivity during the
  rotation?

---

From the documentation:

> Rotation strategy: alternating users
>
> This strategy updates credentials for two users in one secret. You
> create the first user, and during the first rotation, the rotation
> function clones it to create the second user. Every time the secret
> rotates, the rotation function alternates which user's password it
> updates. Because most users don't have permission to clone themselves,
> you must provide the credentials for a superuser in another secret. If
> cloned users in your database don't have the same permissions as the
> original user, often called an ad hoc or interactive user, we
> recommend using the single-user rotation strategy.
>
> This strategy is appropriate for databases with permission models
> where one role owns the database tables and a second role has
> permission to access the database tables. It is also appropriate for
> applications that require high availability. If an application
> retrieves the secret during rotation, the application still gets a
> valid set of credentials. After rotation, both user and user_clone
> credentials are valid. There is even less chance of applications
> getting a deny during this type of rotation than single user rotation.
> If the database is hosted on a server farm where the password change
> takes time to propagate to all servers, there is a risk of the
> database denying calls that use the new credentials. You can mitigate
> this risk with an appropriate retry strategy